# Error while transcoding using FFMPEG from MXF to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I am using FFmpeg 0.6.3 in command line to transcode files from one format to another in windows server 2008.But when i try to convert mxf file to mp4 format. i am getting the following error message

```
ffmpeg error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

ffmpeg command that is used to transcode 
    *ffmpeg -y -i "inputfile.mxf" -t 30 -s 640x360 output.mp4 -t 30 -s 1280x720 output2.mp4*

Comment: Update your question by including the ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output. Otherwise we will have to guess as to what the actual problem is. Also note that ffmpeg usage questions are better suited for superuser.com.

Comment: I'm not so sure. While the question could be said to be about using a program, it is better suited for a programmer audience, I doubt that members of superuser who are not programmers would have knowlegde to really answer that question.

Comment: Unless readily available files are in question, programmers typically use `libav*` libraries and API rather than FFmpeg CLI. Command line argument discussion is hardly a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

i use below command to convert some mxf files. hope these will help you.

```
1]. ffmpeg -i input.mxf -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

above one code is tested and it gives output.mp4 of h264 codec.

you can try some other commands also

```
==> ffmpeg input.mxf -vcodec libx264 -sameq output.mp4
or
==> ffmpeg -i input.mxf -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar -sameq -s 704x400 -r 20 -vcodec libx264 -b 256000 -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method umh -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 2 -bf 1 -coder 1 -me_range 16 -g 300 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 256000 -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 21 output.mp4
```

Hope this will help you :)

PS :- i have followed this page to install ffmpeg to my ubuntu 10.4. install other packages if it gives error of them like libx264

https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuideLucid

Comment: thanks for the reply ..i am using ffmpeg in windows server machine and executing ffmpeg in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

it's a quite a simple answer: Windows server 2008 has no mpeg-4 multiplexer, so you cant get any mp4 info on your machine with default configuration of your server.

-in your computer you can notice that if you stand with your mouse cursor on a video file you will able to see basic file info like duration...

-at your server you might find out that if you do the same on an mp4 media file you will not able to see this information...(duration and dimensions)

the answer for that issue is to go to server manager under the administrative tools in your windows server 2008 r2 from the start menu.

from there you need to choose features in the left side. after that you need to prees add features and select DESKTOP EXPERIENCE and install.

this is the primary thing you need do do for you machine to be able to read mp4 info. after that you need to mime type for your mp4 media files. install codecs.